# How to detect if jquery fullcalendar needs to fetch events from the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am loading 30 days of events. In weekly view I see it is working for 3/4 weeks in weekly view.

Then when I click Next button I see no events.

Is there a way/option to detect that plugin needs to get new events whether I go forward or backward?

Answer (score 0):

You should define this function http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/ and check and load events from  server by ajax like in example.